# Join 1st table with list table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables: first one with records of routes (from->to), the 2nd one with details about each route point (code, name, id)

1st table:

| from_code | to_code |
| --- | --- |
| codeA | codeC |
| codeB | codeD |

2nd table:

| code | name | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| codeA | A | 1 |
| codeB | B | 2 |
| codeC | C | 3 |
| codeD | D | 4 |

As needed result, I need to add name and id to 1st table:

| from_code | from_name | from_id | to_code | to_name | to_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| codeA | A | 1 | codeC | C | 3 |
| codeB | B | 2 | codeD | D | 4 |

How correctly to join them?

Comment: 1st join 2nd on from_code join 2nd on to_code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join to the 2nd table twice, once for the from_code then again for the to_code. You will need to use table Aliases e.g.

```
select  
  a.from_code, 
  b.name as from_name, 
  b.id as from_id, 
  a.to_code, 
  c.name as to_name, 
  c.id as to_id
from table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b 
  on a.from_code = b.code
INNER JOIN table2 c 
  on a.to_code = c.code;`
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 columns in table 1 both require their names etc, to get the names you need a join, so 2 joins are needed.

```
select
      routes.from_code
    , fname.name      as from_name
    , fname.id        as from_id
    , routes.to_code
    , tname.name      as to_name
    , tname.id        as to_id
from table1 as routes
inner join table2 as fname on routes.from_code = fname.code
inner join table2 as tname on routes.to_code = tname.code
```